# how to overlay a directed graph onto an existing community graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The following works as expected:

```
gr1 = Graph[{1 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 1 -> 7, 1 -> 10, 1 -> 13, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6,
 2 -> 8, 2 -> 10, 2 -> 14, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 2, 
14 -> 1}, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 400]
HighlightGraph[gr1, NeighborhoodGraph[gr1, 3]]
```

I cannot overlay a neighborhood graph onto a community graph:

```
HighlightGraph[CommunityGraphPlot[gr1], NeighborhoodGraph[gr1, 3]]
```

Is there a way to achieve this overlay?

Comment: `CommunityGraphPlot[HighlightGraph[gr1, NeighborhoodGraph[gr1, 3]]]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Thanks for this. This is an answer to the question.